# current_user nil while using omniauth with clearance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, omniauth, clearance

This is my sessions controller

```
class SessionsController <  Clearance::SessionsController
  include ActionView::Layouts
  include ActionController::Flash

  def create
    user = AdminUser.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    sign_in(user)
    redirect_to admin_dashboard_index_path
  end
end
```

for some reason my `current_user` is nil when redirected to `admin_dashboard_index_path`. I have `require_login` in all other controllers. So the AD login gets into an indefinite loop. Am I missing any configuration ? All my other controllers are inherting from `AdminController` which inherits from `ActionController::Base`

Comment: are you able to find `user`  in you're session controller create action?

Comment: @uday yes, current_user is there in my sessions controller but disappears after redirect

Comment: what is the response you're getting for `sign_in(user)` ?

Comment: True and it sets the current_user in my sessions controller. When I redirect after sign_in the current_user is set to nil.Please note all my other controllers inherit from AdminController(which inturn inherits from ActionController::Base) and not ApplicationController

Comment: that should update the user in session but have you tried changing the inheritance to ApplicationController for Admin thing?

Comment: No, my appication controller inherts from ActionController Api(since the app was an API app initially) and AdminController  from ActionController Base. Is there any workaround for this ?